# cookie disappeared in AngularJS app using Django and CORS

Tags: django, angularjs, cors, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm building an AngularJS app with Django Rest Framework and Django CORS Headers as backend API.

Everything was working fine until today. Suddenly the `csrfcookie` and `sessionid cookie` stopped showing up in Chrome.

I see the API responding to me with the `csrfcookie`. Chrome doesn't show it in dev tools, however I see it in `chrome://settings/cookies`.

**AngularJS**

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
$http({withCredentials: true, ...})
```

**Django API**

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'x-requested-with',
    'content-type',
    'accept',
    'origin',
    'authorization',
    'X-CSRFToken'
)
```

Comment: You've cleared your cookies right...? Have to ask.

Comment: Hi, yes I cleared all cookies, several times. If i refresh the browser after clearing all cookies I see the csrfcookie again in chrome://settings/cookies, but not in dev tools. AngularJS does not recognize any cookies in the $cookies object.

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally made partial rules to cookies in your browser settings? Also have to ask.

Comment: No. I have not added any exceptions or similiar settings. I fully allow cookies and they show up fine from other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the answer to this issue is quite simple but not always very easy to notice since there are no error messages from the API, nor the client.

[image]

The problem above is that I reside on **domain.com** in my browser, but my request is towards the API is to **"www.domain.com:8000"**. Both **www.domain.com** and **domain.com** are allowed origins in my API.

Conclusion here is that if I reside on **domain.com** then I need to make my API request towards **domain.com:8000**. But if reside on **www.domain.com** in my browser, then I need to make my API request towards **www.domain.com:8000**.

Se a working example down bellow:

[image]

Cookies now appear fine!

I hope this helps anyone, saving a few hours of frustration :)

**Update:**
Enabling the following settings in the Django settings file will also solve the problem. Using them let's you reside on different subdomains in your browser, and the cookies will return for domain ".domain.com"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-domain
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain

Thanks to apollo on irc.freenode.net, #django for the updated answer.

Comment: Could you tell me with this example.. I'm also facing this error,,

Comment: My Browser Side MAMP->192.*.*.*.21:8888/SessionCheck.html , API Server -> 192.*.*.21:8000/api/Login/ Both IP address same with diff port no..though i am using CORS i couldnt set my cookie in brower storage.. What i missed here